# Reusing ViewModel with single View-Instance

Tags: mef, caliburn.micro

I use an MEF exported ViewModel (ReportViewModel) multiple times in my application.

```
   <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding ReportVM}" />
```

As expected, the same instance of the ViewModel is always used. 
But it seems that caliburn always create a new View instance. 
How can I prevent caliburn from creating a new View instance?

Is this possible?